# Не получается протестировать с помощью jest/enzyme часть React компонента. Буду признателен за любую помощь

Tags: reactjs, jest, enzyme

```
const isFileAttached = accepted => !!files.map(({ name }) => name)
    .filter(item => accepted.map(({ name }) => name).includes(item)).length;

const handleDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    setMessage(null);

    if (isFileAttached(acceptedFiles)) {
        setMessage(translations.inputFileNameAttention);
        return;
    }

    if (acceptedFiles.length > maxFilesQuantity || files.length >= maxFilesQuantity) {
        setMessage(
            `${translations.inputFileLimitAttention} ${maxFilesQuantity} ${translations.inputFileLimitAttentionFiles}`
        );
        return;
    }

    if (onDrop) {
        onDrop(acceptedFiles.map(file => {
            if (nonMultimediaMimeTypes.includes(fileMimeType(file.type))) {
                return Object.assign(file, {
                    link: null,
                });
            }

            return Object.assign(file, {
                link: URL.createObjectURL(file),
            });
        }));
    }
}, [onDrop, maxFilesQuantity]);
```